# printing blanks instead of NA's when using formattable in R

Tags: r, formattable

Consider the example data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", "David"), 
  age = c(48, NA, 40, 28),
  test1_score = c(18.9, 19.5, NA, 12.9),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'm using the R package formattable to make a pretty table.

```
library(formattable)
formattable(df, list(
age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
test1_score = color_bar("pink", 'proportion', 0.2)
))
```

[image]

It used to be that NA's were automatically not printed, and a blank was printed instead. It seems like this is no longer the default, but I would still like to print a blank for the NA. Replacing NA like this works:

```
df[is.na(df)]=''
formattable(df, list(
  age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  test1_score = color_bar("pink", 'proportion', 0.2)
))
```

[image]

However if I try to format one of the columns to force it to have 2 decimal places, the pesky NA's return:

```
df$age = digits(df$age, digits=2)
formattable(df, list(
age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
test1_score = color_bar("pink", 'proportion', 0.2)
))
```

[image]

If I remove the NA again, the NA goes away, but so do the decimal places

```
df[is.na(df)] = ''
formattable(df, list(
age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
test1_score = color_bar("pink", 'proportion', 0.2)
))
```

[image]

I believe the reason is that digits converts `df$age` to a `formattable numeric` object and creates the `NA`, and `df[is.na(df)] = ''` converts `df$age` to a `formattable character` object:

```
> df$age = digits(df$age, digits=2)
> df$age
[1] 48.00  NA   40.00 28.00
> class(df$age)
[1] "formattable" "numeric"    
> df[is.na(df)] = ''
> df$age
[1] "48" "  " "40" "28"
> class(df$age)
[1] "formattable" "character"
```

Any ideas on a solution?

Ultimately I'd also like to use this with a filtered data.frame, where I use the code from [Filtering dataframes with formattable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457864/filtering-dataframes-with-formattable) to ensure that the color scale stays the same when filtering the data.frame:

```
df$age = digits(df$age, digits=2)
  subset_df <- function(m) {
    formattable(df[m, ], list(
      age = x ~ color_tile("white", "orange")(df$age)[m],
      test1_score = x ~ color_bar("pink", 'proportion', 0.2)(df$test1_score)[m],
      test2_score = x ~ color_bar("pink", 'proportion', 0.2)(df$test2_score)[m]
    ))
  }

subset_df(1:3)
```

[image]

The problem doesn't seem to be with this code though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `sprintf` function to format the numeric columns as strings with the desired number of decimal places. In the code below, `sprintf` converts `NA` to the string `"NA"`, which we then convert to an empty string.

```
# Function to convert numeric values to strings with a given number of 
#  decimal places, and convert NA to empty string
fnc = function(var, decimal.places) {
  var = sprintf(paste0("%1.",decimal.places,"f"), var)
  var[var=="NA"] = ""
  var
}

# Select the columns we want to reformat
vars = c('age', 'test1_score')

# Apply the function to the desired columns with the desired number of decimal places
df[ , vars] = mapply(fnc, df[ ,vars], 2:3)

formattable(df, list(
  age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  test1_score = color_bar("pink", 'proportion', 0.2)
))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which worked for me was using `str_remove_all()`.  Because `color_bar()` in `formattable` produces HTML output as a character, you can just remove the string "NA".

**Note that this has the potential to mess up the HTML if you happened to have `NA` anywhere else.** Also worth noting is that I wrap a percent function around `your_var`. 
 This was the best way I could come up with to convert my numeric to percent and apply `color_bar()`.  The code is below:

```
df %>%
    # First mutate w/color_bar()
    mutate(your_var= color_bar("green", na.rm=T)(percent(your_var, digits = 1))) %>% 
    # Second mutate
    mutate(your_var = str_remove_all(your_var, "NA"))
```

### Output from First mutate

```
<span style="display: inline-block; direction: rtl; border-radius: 4px; padding-right: 2px; background-color: #00a657">NA</span>
```

### Output from Second mutate

```
<span style="display: inline-block; direction: rtl; border-radius: 4px; padding-right: 2px; background-color: #00a657"></span>
```

Also, in case anyone hasn't seen this yet: [Awesome tables in HTML - Integration with formattable](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#integration_with_formattable)